# WebGL- After rendering the mesh correctly some triangles disappear

Tags: opengl-es, geometry, rendering, webgl

My problem is the following. I have a canvas in which I am drawing a piece using WebGL.
When it renders, it is fine.

But then, two seconds later or so, without moving the camera or anything, some of the triangles disappear.

And after moving the camera or something, the triangles that are gone stays the same (I have read that in some cases is due to the buffer and the distance to the object so by zooming in or out the triangles that are gone can change).

What could be the problem?
I am applying both color and texture to each element in order to print black lines around each "square" (my texture is a square with black border and white inside). That means that the final color is computed in the fragment shader by multiplying the color times the texture. That also means that some of the nodes are duplicated or even more (in order to give the TextureVertex attribute to a node I need a different node as it belongs to each element) It is important to notice that, when I create a mesh with less number of nodes, they do not disappear. Anyway, I have seen WebGL examples on the net very complex, and I may have just 1000 nodes so I don't think it could be a problem of my graphic hardware.
What do you think could be the problem? How would you solve it? If you require more info just let me know. I didn't include code because it seems to be rendered OK at the beginning, and furthermore I only have this problem with "big" meshes.

Thanks for the comment. please find here both images:

First draw

[image: First draw]

A few seconds later.

[image: A few seconds later]

EDITED: Im gonna give some more details in case this helps to find the problem. I will give you the information regarding one of the squares (the rest of the squares would follow same scheme). Notice that they are defined in the code behind as public variables and then I pass them to the html script:

Nodes for vertex buffer:

> serverSideInitialCoordinates = {
>
> ```
>             -1.0,-1.0,0.0,
>             1.0,-1.0,0.0,
>             1.0,1.0,0.0,
>             -1.0,1.0,0.0,
>             0.0,-1.0,0.0,
>             1.0,0.0,0.0,
>             0.0,1.0,0.0,
>             -1.0,0.0,0.0,
>             0.0,0.0,0.0,
>                                    };
> ```

Connectivity to form triangles:

> serverSideConnectivity = {
>                   0,4,8,
>                   0,8,7,
>                   1,5,8,
>                   1,8,4,
>                   2,6,8,
>                   2,8,5,
>                   3,7,8,
>                   3,8,6
>
> ```
>                                       };
> ```

Colors:not relevant.
TextureVertex:{

> ```
>             0.0,0.0
>             1.0,0.0
>             1.0,1.0
>             0.0,1.0
>             0.5,0.0
>             1.0,0.5
>             0.5,1.0
>             0.0,0.5
>             0.5,0.5                 
>
>                                       };
> ```
>
> As I mentioned I have an image which is white with just few pixels black around the borders. So in the fragment shader I have something similar to this:

gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord) * vColor;

Then I have a function that loads the image and gets the texture.
In the function InitBuffers I create the buffers and assign to them the vertexPosition, The colors and the connectivity of the triangles.

Finally in the Draw function I bind the buffers again : vertexPosition, color (bind it as colorattribute), texture (bind it as textureVertex), and connectivity, and then set Matrix Uniform and draw. I don think the problem is here because it works fine for smaller meshes, but I still dont know why it doesn't for larger ones. I thought maybe performance of firefox is worse than other browsers' but then I ran on firefox difficult WebGL models I found on the web and they work fine, no triangles missing. If I print same objects without the texture (just colors) it works fine and no triangles are missing. Do you think that maybe it takes a lot of effort for the shader to get the color everytime by multiplying both things? Can you think of another way?

My idea was just to draw black lines between some nodes instead of using a complete texture, but I cant get it working, either I draw the triangles or I draw the lines but it doesn't allow me to draw both at same time. If I put code for both, only the last "elements" are drawn.

Comment: A picture would definitely help, you can use http://imgur.com/ for uploading images. Also, it would be good to atleast share the vertex, index and texture cooordinate arrays you are using to draw.

Comment: I added the images. The problem is that My mesh is nearly 1500 nodes or even more, so I cannot put the nodes directly here. Furthermore they are passed from another program (from code behind) in which I generate them, they are not defined directly in the html tag.

Comment: Since for small meshes it works I thought they are done correctly. I have the mesh divided into squares as you see in the image. Each square has 9 nodes (4 each vertex, four mid-sides and one in the center, as forming four smaller squares) and so I form 8 triangles. In order to apply different color to each square, I have more than one node in a specific point in the space (one belonging to each adjacent element). So I go square by square creating the nodes, then assigning as many colors as nodes, and finally defining the connectivity to form triangles. And I store each thing in a buffer

Comment: Are the missing triangles in exactly the same plane as the other triangles top and bottom ? And is that plane parallel to the y axis ? Or is there a bulge/curvature in the middle ?

Comment: I have changed the images, now you should see them better. Missing triangles should be in the same plane as the others around. Though in previous example the pattern was clearly two lines of triangles in Y direction, in other meshes such as this one it goes in zig zag or whatever, so it depends. They are well rendered at the beginning but then after some seconds is as if the data is corrupted or something. I must say that if I call again the function that prints the object, the missing triangles are THE SAME for that geometry in particular..

Comment: example of a smaller mesh which doesnt suffer this problem:http://imgur.com/ozpAL8Q

Comment: This looks more like a power management or related issue in the GPU. Have you tried this on multiple platforms ?

Comment: Please embed your images if you update them.

Comment: gman sorry but I cant embed them, or I am very stupid to know how to do that I'm sorry. @prabindh I agree with you that it is more likely a problem at the GPU rather than with the code itself, otherwise it doesn't make much sense. I have added some more information. If any of u have any suggestions regarding how to improve efficiency or how to correct it, it would be great. I have not tried it yet in another computer, but I will. Furthermore I will try in Chrome just in case and I will let you know if anything changes

Comment: Hey, I have just discovered that I have a similar problem when rendering this example of the WebGL tutorial. It renders fine at first, I see the laptop, the moon and the box. However, few seconds later some of the triangles inside the screen (some of the moon) as well as some triangles of the laptop disappear. So this may be a problem with my GPU. Please could you test whether you have the same problem?? I would appreciate your feedback. Here is a link to that example: http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson16/, and also lesson 11: http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson11/index.html

Comment: Are you sure that GPU produce this? Do you tested any OpenGL/Direct3D application? Does this thing happening there too? Which drivers are you using? Also, what browser (+version) are you using?

Comment: I'm realizing that it could be a problem of the specific computer in which I am working now. It is not dependent on the browser (same happens with Chrome and Firefox, versions Chrome 32.0.1700.76 and Firefox 26.0). I remember I saw these lessons on my laptop without this problem. I have not tried yet any app of OpenGl, I will try and let you know.This is a 64-bits Intel i7, Windows 7 OS, with 12gb RAM and using ATI Radeon HD 3400 series..